# How can I access "\appdata\roaming", go down a few directories, and then search for a file?

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010, search, file-io, application-data

My program (Visual Basic 2010) has to run on different people's machines, so I have to use a relative path like %appdata%, but I also have to get a file from a randomly named directory. its like this:

```
C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Roaming\Dir1\Dir2\Dir3\Random-NameDir\file
```

Also, the randomly named directory is the only one in Dir3. (BTW im trying to get the filepath)

I can use this, but it does not get through the random directory (and i cant find a way to search with the environment class there)

```
Dim a As New Attachment(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.ApplicationData) & "\Dir1\Dir2\Dir3")
```

And when i try this,

```
For Each foundFile As String In My.Computer.FileSystem.GetFiles( _
    My.Computer.FileSystem.SpecialDirectories.CurrentUserApplicationData & "\Dir1\Dir2\Dir3", _
    FileIO.SearchOption.SearchAllSubDirectories, "MyFile.ext")
    ListBox1.Items.Add(foundFile)
    Next
```

AppData sends me to WindowsApplicaiton1\1.0.0 somthing which is a folder in appdata\roaming.

Basically my question is, Can I search for a file, limiting the search to only the randomly named directory (which is in application data), in order to get the file path that I can then use as an attachment for an email?